# Welcher Unterschied besteht zwischen „ist“ und „wurde gemacht“?

Tags: grammar, meaning, difference, passive

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Formen: 
*… **ist** gemacht* und *… **wurde** gemacht*?

> Der Brief ist geschrieben.
>   Der Brief wurde geschrieben.

Comment: Das eine ist Zustandspassiv, das andere „normales“ Passiv. Außerdem unterscheiden sie sich in der Zeitstufe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wie bereits von @chirlu korrekt beantwortet:

> Das eine ist Zustandspassiv, das andere „normales“ Passiv. Außerdem unterscheiden sie sich in der Zeitstufe.

Als erklärende Ergänzung zu den Sätzen (auch wenn der Unterschied in der Bedeutung nur marginal ist):

Imho wird das Zustandspassiv in diesem Kontext tendenziell eher für Aktionen genutzt, auf die der Schreiber/Sprecher Einfluss hatte und das "normale" Passiv für den Rest: "Der Brief ist abgeschickt." würde ich benutzen, wenn mich jemand fragt, ob ich einen Brief bereits abgeschickt habe. "Der Brief wurde abgeschickt." würde ich hingegen eher benutzen, wenn jemand anderes dafür zuständig war. Beispielsweise: "Ja, unsere Bestellung wurde von dem Lieferanten abgeschickt".

Im normalen Sprachgebrauch ist dies aber keine extrem harte Regel und man wird in der Regel auch gut verstanden werden.

Answer (score 2):

Die traditionelle Grammatik beschreibt, wie schon von BenSower geschrieben, die *wurde*-Form als Handlungspassiv und die *ist*-Form als Zustandspassiv. Die *wurde*-Form bezeichnet dabei eher Handlungen, die in der Vergangenheit, um die es geht, stattgefunden haben, während die *ist*-Form eher verwendet wird, wenn die Handlung in der Vergangenheit bereits abgeschlossen war.

Man kann die *ist*-Form allerdings auch, abweichend vom Standard, als adjektivisches Partizip auffassen. Dann beschreibt sie einen Zustand, den der Brief *in der Gegenwart* hat, unabhängig davon, wann er den Zustand erhalten hat. Und es ist auch möglich, das Partizip attributiv zu verwenden:

> Der Brief ist abgeschickt.
>
> Der *abgeschickte* Brief ist angekommen.
>
> Ich habe den *abgeschickten und angekommenen* Brief gelesen.

Answer (score -6):

Die verhangenheitsform von 'ist' bezeichnet man als 'wurde'. 'Ist' bezeichnet den jetzigen zustand. 'Wurde' bezeichnet den neuen vorherigen zustand.

Comment: Aber "ist gemacht" ist auch Vergangenheit oder?

Comment: Und ich dachte immer, die Vergangenheitsform von "ist" sei "war"...