# Warum steht das Subjekt manchmal nach dem Objekt?

Tags: word-order

Manchmal sehe ich diesen besonderen Fall und ich muss mich immer noch fragen, warum das Objekt vor dem Subjekt steht. In anderen Fällen heißt es, dass ein "es" fehlt, z.B. in diesem Satz:

> Mir wird von ihr geholfen

Aber bei diesem Fall wird Passiv nicht verwendet, aber noch steht das Subjekt im falschen Platz:

> "Der Brief ist abgeschickt." würde ich benutzen, **wenn mich jemand fragt**, ob ich einen Brief bereits abgeschickt habe.

Was ist hier die Regel? Ich hätte den Satz so gebildet: "... wenn jemand mich fragt, ..."

Vielleicht übersehe ich etwas einfaches.

Dieser Satz wurde original hier geschrieben: [Welcher Unterschied besteht zwischen „ist“ und „wurde gemacht“?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27826/welcher-unterschied-besteht-zwischen-ist-und-wurde-gemacht)

Comment: Willkommen. Ich sehe verschiedene Fragen. Zu dem Teil „*mich  jemand* anstelle *jemand mich*“ siehe [diese Frage und die erste Antwort](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6474/where-to-place-sich-in-an-elaborate-sentence)

Comment: Ich stelle in meinem Eintrag nur eine Frage. Es gab den ersten Teil nur, weil ich erklären wollte, dass meine Frage anders war. Ich gebe zu, ich könnte meine Frage besser bilden. Hätte ich mit dem zweiten Teil anfangen sollen?

Danke für den Link, ich schaue ihn jetzt an.

Comment: In den Link steht es, dass ein Reflexivpronomen vor dem Nomen kommt. Aber in meinem Fall gibt es keinen Reflexivpronomen. Ist Reflexivpronomen derselbe wie die Akkusativform von Pronomen?

Comment: Nein, es ist kein Reflexivpronomen. Aber es gibt schlicht keine Regel, die besagen würde, daß das Subjekt am Anfang kommen muß. Beide Positionen, _wenn jemand mich fragt_ und _wenn mich jemand fragt_, sind möglich.

Comment: Okay, mit diesem Link verstehe ich endlich. In Nebensätzen muss das Verb nur am Ende kommen, alles inzwischen können irgendwo passen. Natürlich würde es eine beste Ordnung geben.