# What is the difference between "ist" und "wurde"

Tags: verb

What is the difference between the two sentences:

> Das Buch wurde geschrieben.
>
> Das Buch ist geschrieben.

---

Hinweis: Die Frage wurde [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27826/welcher-unterschied-besteht-zwischen-ist-und-wurde-gemacht) auf Deutsch beantwortet.

Comment: What does your grammar book say? And why are you unsatisfied with its explanation?

Comment: Here answered in German: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27826/welcher-unterschied-besteht-zwischen-ist-und-wurde-gemacht

Comment: @close voters: The same question was accepted and answered in German.

Comment: @iris Then it's a duplicate. SE provides means to mark it as such.

Comment: @PerlDuck, no, it is okay to have questions twice, in German and English.

Comment: siehe meta: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/14/if-the-same-question-is-asked-in-german-and-english-is-it-a-duplicate

Comment: @Iris I wasn't aware of this policy here but when thinking about it it seems reasonable. I actually wanted to mark this Q as a dupe but either I mis-clicked or sth. else went wrong. The moment I hit OK, the Q was put on hold with my name as one of the off-topic voters. I apologize for tipping the scales.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in answers to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27826/welcher-unterschied-besteht-zwischen-ist-und-wurde-gemacht) in German, the case with *ist* is called *Zustandspassiv* (stative passive) and I would translate it simply to “The book is written”, which just emphasizes the state, independent of when it was created in the past. The case with *wurde* is the *Handlungspassiv* (dynamic passive) and would be translated to “The book was written”, emphasizing the act of writing it.

There is a difference in time, the *ist* case doesn’t specify a time, the *wurde* case took place in the past.

There might not be many differences in practice. For example I could say both:

> Das Buch wurde von Shakespeare geschrieben.
>
> Das Buch ist von Shakespeare geschrieben.

And both would mean that Shakespeare is the author of the book.